# git-svn clone with weird svn tags organization

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I want to clone a SVN tree into a git repo using git-svn. I'd like to make a complete clone, including tags and branches, but I hit a problem with the tags organization.

the SVN tags folder looks like this:

```
tags/
|-- Backup
|   |-- 20080212
|   `-- 20080217
|-- V4.0.1
|-- V4.0.2
`-- V4.0.3
```

I know about `git svn clone -T trunk -b branches -t tags/Backup -t tags` with twice the `-t` option, but this is not entirely satisfying:

```
$ git branch -r
  tags/20080212
  tags/20080217
  tags/Backup
  tags/V4.0.1
  tags/V4.0.2
  tags/V4.0.3
  trunk
```

As you can see, all the tags are here, but one is too much: the **Backup** tag is actually not a tag but a folder containing tags. The problem is that it creates an orphan branch which duplicate the content of all the backup branches.

The question is: How do I make git-svn ignore the backup folder but know about the backup subfolders as tags, keeping the classical tags available?

And as a bonus: how to automatically name the Backup tags as `Backup/20080217` instead of `20080217`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git svn` isn't intelligent enough to be able to ignore the Backup folder in one group of tags but include its subfolders. You've a bunch of options, none of which are great:

- Change the underlying Subversion repository to move *all* the tags into subfolders, so your repository looks something like this:

  ```
  tags/
  |--Backup/
  |  |--20080212
  |  `--20080217
  `--Versions/
     |--V4.0.1
     |--V4.0.2
     `--V4.0.3
  ```

  You can then use `-t tags/Backup -t tags/Versions` to pick up all the tags.
- Cope.  While irritating, the way Git manages tree objects means having a "Backup" tag won't actually take any more space or slow down most Git operations; the only impact will be `git svn fetch`es will take longer.
- Write your own patch for `git-svn` to enable handling this scenario. Bonus points if you get it included in future official Git releases.

Getting the tags to have a different name is fairly easy, at least. If you edit your `.git/config` file, you should find a line that looks something like this:

```
tags = tags/Backup/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

You should be able to change this to the below instead:

```
tags = tags/Backup/*:refs/remotes/tags/Backup/*
```

If you do this between running `git svn init` and the first `git svn fetch`, everything should just work. Otherwise, you may need to manually remove the old references first, by deleting any files or folders with a name matching the tag name in `.git/logs/refs/remotes/tags/`, `.git/svn/refs/remotes/tags/` and `.git/refs/remotes/tags`.

I have no idea what will happen if you have a tag called "Backup" and a folder of tags called "Backup", though. I suspect nothing good. You'll need to find some way of avoiding that, or store the Backup tags in a folder with a different name.

Comment: Thanks for the long answer. Renaming the tags fails as you describe it with the following: `error: unable to create directory for .git/refs/remotes/tags/Backup/20080212
fatal: Cannot lock the ref 'refs/remotes/tags/Backup/20080212'.
update-ref -m r175 refs/remotes/tags/Backup/20080212 b1aa4898486b123aa6c270e657ee49ffbd8ed3ad: command returned error: 128`

Comment: Can you tell me the result of `file .git/refs/remotes/tags/Backup`? If that comes up as something other than "directory", it means it can't create the folder called "Backup" because there's already a tag with that name. As I said in the last paragraph, I'd give that folder a different name to avoid that clash; possibly use `tags = tags/Backup/*:refs/remotes/tags/bkutags/*` or similar in place of the config line I suggested in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) to clone the repository, it creates correct tags, provides better translation and works faster than git-svn.

Comment: It won't clone a local svn from a file:/// url

Comment: Yes, things changed since my answer, older SmartGit could work with file:// protocol